# youtube doesn't work well

Tags: sound, video, youtube

I replaced Windows 8 with Ubuntu. But now when I watch YouTube videos the video player does not work very well in 1080p. It sometimes does not load or stops and buffers every 30 seconds or so. Sometimes the video is slower than the audio. When I press pause it sometimes runs a few seconds longer, also the video is sometimes not running smoothly. All in all it's a very ugly experience. I hope someone can help me. Please keep in mind that I am an unexperienced user. Thank you.

Comment: Hi, ich habe das mal auf Englisch übersetzt, dann können dir sicherlich mehr Leute helfen. Es wäre toll wenn du in deine Frage noch rein schreiben könntest welchen Browser du verwendest. Ich denke mal du benutzt den Firefox, oder?

Comment: Since this is an english website, I will now write english only, so people having the same problem like you can understand what solved your problems. Welcome to askubuntu :)

Answer (score 1):

I hope this will help you.

- Start the Software Centre
- search for "ubuntu-restricted-extras"
- The result of this search should be only one package. Install it.

You maybe need to restart your computer.